# Function within function within function seems to be losing temporary variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, scoping, object-reference

I can't understand why my code is not working. Simply put, there are three function levels: an access function to initiate the process, a DOB function which is the core of the program, and several functions within including a PROBLEM function that I labeled for the sake of identification.

If I run the DOB function with numbers that I input directly, it works. But when the user selects numbers from a dropdown menu, the PROBLEM function within fails. I had a jquery go button before changing to an access function with temporary variables only to get the same results. I tried changing the PROBLEM function from switches to if-elses to changing the name, but nothing that I modified worked.

This problem has been stumping me for nearly a week. I am brand new to coding and teaching myself so I may be missing some obvious scoping or object reference problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (The code has been simplified with all key components intact.)((Leap Year function within DOB function needing same temporary variables seems to work.))

Update: made minor changes. Tested a lot. Problem function remains the culprit and I don't understand why. If I enter numerical values, it works fine, but it won't take the values from that I have tried to store from the form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
        <form id="myForm" class="form">
                <p><b>&nbsp;Month</b></p>
                <select id="Bmonth" class="date">
                    <option value="1">January</option>
                    <option value="2">February</option>
                    <option value="3">March</option>
                </select>
                <p><b>Day</b></p>
                <select id="Bdom" class="date">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
                <p><b>Year</b> </p>
                <select id="Byear" class="date">
                    <option value="2015">2015</option>
                    <option value="2014">2014</option>
                    <option value="2013">2013</option>
                </select>
            <p class="clear">
                <input type="button" onclick="access()" value="Submit">
            </p>
        </form>

<script>
    function access() {
        var tempElement = document.getElementById("Bmonth");
        Bmonth = tempElement.options[tempElement.selectedIndex].value;

        var tempElement = document.getElementById("Bdom");
        Bdom = tempElement.options[tempElement.selectedIndex].value;

        var tempElement = document.getElementById("Byear");
        Byear = tempElement.options[tempElement.selectedIndex].value;

        return DOB(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear);
    }

/*This function determines time intervals
between birth date and current date.*/
function DOB(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear) {

    //Get Current Date//
    var today = new Date();
    var Cmonth = today.getMonth();
    var Cdom = today.getDate();
    var Cyear = today.getFullYear();

    function PROBLEM(Month, DOM) {
    switch (Month) {
    case 1: return 0 + DOM; break;
    case 2: return 31 + DOM; break;
    case 3: return 59+ DOM; break;
        }
    }
    /*Find Current and Birth Day of Year
    By Calling Function Above */
    CDOY = PROBLEM(Cmonth + 1, Cdom);
    BDOY = PROBLEM(Bmonth, Bdom);

    //Find Differences//
    var DayCount = CDOY - BDOY;
    var YearCount = Cyear - Byear;

// This function determines the number of leap years//
    function Leap(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear, Cmonth, Cyear) {
       var LeapYear = 0;
       if ((Byear % 4 == 0 && (Byear % 100 !== 0 || Byear % 400 == 0)) &&

(Bmonth >= 3 || Bmonth == 2 && Bdom == 29)) {
LeapYear--;
}
       if ((Cyear % 4 == 0 && (Cyear % 100 !== 0 || Cyear % 400 == 0)) &&

Cmonth < 3) {
LeapYear--;
}
       for (var i = Cyear; i >= Byear; i--) {
           if ((i % 4 == 0) && ((i % 100 !== 0) || (i % 400 == 0)))
{ LeapYear++; };
}
       return LeapYear;
}
//Call function above//
    var LeapYear = Leap(Bmonth, Bdom, Byear, Cmonth, Cyear);

//Find Total Days//
    var TotalDays = 365 * YearCount + DayCount + LeapYear;

//Find Variables//
var Days = TotalDays;
var Hours = Days * 24;
var Minutes = Hours * 60;
var Seconds = Minutes * 60;

var Output, Units;
//Use Random Number Generator to Vary Output with Units//
var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
switch (random) {
case 1: Output = Days; Units = 'days old.'; break;
case 2: Output = Hours; Units = 'hours old.'; break;
case 3: Output = Minutes; Units = 'minutes old.'; break;
case 4: Output = Seconds; Units = 'seconds old.'; break;
default: Output = 0; Units = 'units.'; break;
}

var Greeting;
//Use Random Number Generator to Vary Greeting//
var r = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 3);
switch (r) {
case 1: Greeting = 'Congrats!'; break;
case 2: Greeting = 'Yes!'; break;
case 3: Greeting = 'Check it.'; break;
}
function commas(x) {
return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
var Number = commas(Output);

return window.alert(Greeting + "You are " + Number + " " + Units); 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `case 1: return = 0 + DOM; break;` everything after the keyword `return` will never be evaluated. Remove the `=` in those lines. You can also remove all `break;` there.

Comment: That was my mistake. I keep updating what I have in there. The function I have works fine when I input actual numbers, but it won't take the numbers stored as temporary variables from the dropdown menu in that particular function.

Answer (score 0):

`PROBLEM` does not return any value, which means that

```
CDOY = PROBLEM(Cmonth + 1, Cdom);
BDOY = PROBLEM(Bmonth, Bdom);
```

Results in `CDOY` and `BDOY` always being `undefined`. Try this:

```
function PROBLEM(Month, DOM) {
  switch (Month) {
    case 1: return 0;
    case 2: return 31;
    case 3: return 59;
  }
}
```

---

Aside: I strongly recommend getting a comfortable stepping through your code in a debugger, so you can understand exactly what's happening every step of the way. Good luck, and don't give up!

Comment: Thanks for the advice and encouragement. Your solution is much simpler, but it still doesn't work. I will work on the debuggers. I tried a couple the one in Virtual Studio but it wouldn't let me do anything because of the Object Reference Error. Firebug seemed to miss it but perhaps I did it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate this board and all of the suggestions. I guess I was asking for it by stating problems within functions in functions in functions. I have been able to resolve the problem by using:

```
    return DOB(Number(Bmonth), Number(Bdom), Number(Byear));
```

I did not realize that the variables were not being transferred as actual numbers. Go figure.

Answer (score -1):

Never nest function declaration (named function) in another function declaration. E.g. extract this from the parent function, and return the result.

```js
function PROBLEM(Month, DOM) {
    var MAD;
    switch (Month) {
        case 1: MAD = 0; break;
        case 2: MAD = 31; break;
        case 3: MAD = 59; break;
    }
    return MAD;
}
```

Then in the DOB function you call this snippet like

```js
var MAD = PROBLEM(Bmonth, Cdom);
```

Do this for all your function calls and retest it.

Comment: I tried this for the one function, but it still didn't work. Am I wrong to try and run the whole program as a function?

Comment: When you have extracted every nested function to outside of any function, a big good step is done. So you can use those functions also for other tasks. When some are functions that are only meaningful in a certain function (nested), a  [closure (anonymous function)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) is the right thing for you. Then the next thing to do is to debug your code, look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp).

Comment: _"Never nest function declaration in another function declaration"_ is rather heavyhanded. There are plenty of occasions where that's fine.

Comment: Interesting. Which occasions could that be? And i did not mean closures (anonymous functions), but nested declared (named) functions.

Comment: I get the idea now about the functions. I pulled them all out and only called them when needed, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Nesting a function inside another function is often highly desirable and a core feature of Javascript called *closure* .

Comment: @connexo: **Please** check my messages completely. I explicitly was talking about **declared (named) functions** that should not be nested. I also mentioned that a closure would be the right thing if nested. Said so, now you can re-think the downvote. @ CJW. Did you try to debug? Before i linked you a good link [here. Klickme](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp)

Comment: what the difference between _declared (named) functions_ and _anonymous functions_ so first _should not be nested_ and second _should be_?